# Invertible matrix 2019

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

Let $A\in M_{n\times n}(\mathbb{C})$ be an invertible matrix.
Show that there exist $u\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\lambda\in\mathbb{C}$ not null, such that $u=\frac{1}{\lambda^n}A^nu$

And I am not able to do this, say whether it is true or false and justify with a demonstration or an example,
$A,B\in M_{5\times 5}(\mathbb{C})$ similar matrices and u is a vector of A then  $\sqrt2u$ is a proper vector of B

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Do you really mean $u \in \mathbb{R}^n$?  I don't think the statement is necessarily true with that requirement.  For example, if $A = \begin{bmatrix} \cos \theta & -\sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & \cos \theta \end{bmatrix}$ then $A^2 = \begin{bmatrix} \cos(2\theta) & -\sin(2\theta) \\ \sin(2\theta) & \cos(2\theta) \end{bmatrix}$.  Then if $\theta = \pi/4$ the eigenvectors of $A^2$ are $(1, i)$ and $(1, -i)$ and no (complex) scalar multiple of either of these is in $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: the statement is true, but I do not know how to solve this, I have already tried to start from the expression u

Comment: No, it's false. You've been given a counterexample. It's true if you change $u\in\Bbb R^n$ to $u\in\Bbb C^n$.

Comment: and making this change so I can solve how I do it $u=\frac{1}{\lambda^n}A^nu $ give me a light ?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**  You just need a nonzero eigenvalue. Invertibility actually implies none of the eigenvalues are $0$.

Answer (score 0):

What we need here is for $A$ to have an eigenvalue/eigenvector. Since $A^n$ are just repeated mappings of the linear transformation represented by the matrix $A$, obviously, the eigenvalue will be scaled by a power of $n$ and the eigenvector remains unchanged. That is, if $Ax=\lambda x$, then $A^nx=\lambda^n x$. This is precisely the equation in the question! Can you continue from here?

---

Edit: Here are some more details to help you along. As shown above we just require some $\lambda\neq0$ to exist such that $\det(A-\lambda I)=0$. $A$ is invertible, so $\det(A-0I)\neq0$ and if such a $\lambda$ exists, then it can't be $0$. So we really only need to prove that *the characteristic polynomial of $A$ has a complex root*. Is this obvious to you?

Comment: Thanks, but I can not explain the issue, I've been trying to apply the rules of the manual but :( It would be possible to detail a little

Comment: @Monica Please see the edit.

Comment: Thank you, I got it, and about the second part of the question, something you can help me with.